# How to get bash to suggest a missing package?

Tags: debian, command-line

While running Ubuntu, while trying to execute a command in bash, it used to suggest that the said program was missing but found in another package Y, and that I could try installing it.

Now on a Debian system, that's no longer the case. If the command isn't found it doesn't suggest anything, but the package manager list is updated. How can I get it to suggest a package from commands given in bash?

Answer (score 17):

I am guessing you would need to install a package. From what I can tell it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

Should hopefully be in the default Debian repos.